# MVCContrib Grid Paging customization

Tags: asp.net-mvc, grid, paging, customization, mvccontrib

Is it possible to customize the Pager from the MVCContrib project?
Right now i use this code (to page in german):

```
@Html.Pager((MvcContrib.Pagination.IPagination)Model.deals)
.First("Erste")
.Last("Letzte")
.Next("Naechste")
.Previous("Vorherige")
```

and the resulting display is this:

```
Showing 1 - 2 of 5 Erste | Vorherige | Naechste | Letzte
```

Is it possible to show the text "Showing"..."of" also in german?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

This was rather easy:

simply add the following:

```
.Format( "Anzeige {0}-{1} von {2} | " )
```